# split multiple active class every 5 second and loop

Tags: javascript

How to split all code working together at the same time, with unlimited different classes and loop in animated class. Code is like this but i want to make it run at the same time, and put it with unlimited of animated class.

```js
$(function() {
    var lis = $(".animated > .boxed"),
        currentHighlight = 0;
        
        N = 5;//interval in seconds
    setInterval(function() {
        currentHighlight = (currentHighlight + 1) % lis.length;
        lis.removeClass('highlighted').eq(currentHighlight).addClass('highlighted');
    },  1000);
});
```

```css
.boxed {
  background-color: red;
  padding:5px;
}


.highlighted {
    background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="animated">
    <span class="boxed">1</span>
    <span class="boxed">2</span>
    <span class="boxed">3</span>
</span>
<p>

</p>
  <span class="animated">
    <span class="boxed">1</span>
    <span class="boxed">2</span>
    
    <span class="boxed">3</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are number of ways for doing this but basically you need to handle each of the "animated"-containers separately. Now you are looping through all the "boxed"-elements on the page which is not what you want if I understood you correctly. Loop the "boxed"-elements inside each "animated"-container:

```js
$(function() {
  const highlightClass = "highlighted";
  
  $(".animated").each(function() {
    var $container = $(this);
    var $lis = $container.find(".boxed");

    setInterval(function() {
      var $highlighted = $container.find("." + highlightClass);

      $highlighted.removeClass(highlightClass);

      if ($highlighted.length == 0 || $highlighted.next().length == 0) {
        $container.find(".boxed").first().addClass(highlightClass);
      } else {
        $highlighted.next().addClass(highlightClass);
      }
    }, 1000);
  });

});
```

```css
.boxed {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 5px;
}

.highlighted {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>
  <span class="animated">
    <span class="boxed">1</span>
  <span class="boxed">2</span>
  <span class="boxed">3</span>
  </span>
</p>
<p>
  <span class="animated">
    <span class="boxed">1</span>
  <span class="boxed">2</span>

  <span class="boxed">3</span>
  </span>
</p>
<p>
  <span class="animated">
    <span class="boxed">1</span>
  <span class="boxed">2</span>

  <span class="boxed">3</span>
  </span>
</p>
```

Comment: Can you also make all animated is stop when the mouse is hover on one of boxed and continue when its out